# "You're keeping well" vs "You keep doing well"

Tags: phrase-usage

> I hope you are keeping well.

and

> I hope you keep doing well

Are they essentially the same thing?

Answer (score 4):

No, they mean different things.

"Keeping well" means "keeping healthy". So "I hope you're keeping well" is a slightly old fashioned greeting. It might be addressed to an older person (for whom being "well" might be in some doubt). I can't imagine a child using it with their friends.

To "keep doing well" is not an idiom. "Well" is the adverb related to "good". The speaker is hoping that the other person continues to do something in a good manner Eg.

> -- I've got over 90% in all my maths tests this year.
>
> -- That's great. I hope you keep doing well.

Answer (score 0):

In a way they mean the same, but I don't think a native speaker would say the second. A better paraphrase of the first is "I hope you continue to be well".

Comment: "I hope you are keeping well" sounds a little old-fashioned and formal to this American English speaker, but [it's perfectly idiomatic and still in live usage](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22i+hope+you+are+keeping+well%22).  For example: ["Dear Ned, I hope you are keeping well and I miss you."](https://books.google.com/books?id=yzMzo3vRxzAC&pg=PA252&dq=%22i+hope+you+are+keeping+well%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjumt_w3YTLAhXLWj4KHXkMDdIQ6AEIHTAA)

Comment: I could see myself saying the second, but it would mean something different. _I hope you keep doing well **in school**,_ for example.

Answer (score -2):

> Shopper at a grocery store:  How long do they keep?
>   Produce salesman:  If you keep them in a dark, cool, dry place, they should keep for months.

"I hope you are keeping well" means "I hope you are not rotting, like a fruit (or vegetable, or meat) that is going bad."

"I hope you are staying well" means "I hope you continue to be healthy."  This sentence is in the present tense, not the future tense.

"I hope you keep doing well" means "I hope that you continue to do good things, and have good things happen to you."  This sentence is in the future tense.

Comment: I've heard people say "I hope you are keeping well", and it does not literally mean "I hope you are not rotting like a piece of fruit."  The meaning is closer to "I hope you are remaining well."